Laravel Jetstream Auth open the home page but Apex chart not showing
I am new to Laravel and using Sneat Dashboard for home project. All is working fine until I used Jetstream for login and logout.
After Jetstream installation, dashboard opened with all data, except apex chart is not showing.
Thanks in Advance
Below is my web.php
`// Main Page Route
  Route::get('/', [EcommerceDashboard::class, 'index'])->name('app-ecommerce-dashboard'); // Open Web dairy Page

Fortify
`'home' => '/',``

If I open another page, it opens properly with chart. Issue is only for Dashboard.
